# How to run same flask app.py file on different ports?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to run my same app.py file on different ports. For example: By creating
app1.py:5000

app2.py:5001 and taking their port addresses in an array to divide the load from the server.
Actually, I am doing this because my client side is sending 10 fps to the server. By continuous post requests it gives an error, connection aborted timeout('10060' .
So if there any other solution kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in production try to use some good real web server options. You can use `Nginx`
for your use case if you arent working on a windows server. You do still have some good options like Gunicorn. Gunicorn is an easy-to-use WSGI server that will let you help to handle your load on the server.